# What does “before the question gets closed” mean?

Tags: discussion, closing, comments

I have seen more than a few people writing a comment which starts with “Before the question gets closed” when they can predict that the question will be closed.  I cannot understand what it means because we can post comments after the question is closed in the same way as before it is closed if I am not mistaken.  What is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it just stems from the mistaken belief that one cannot comment after a question has been closed. I used to think that too, before I saw it being done recently. Actually now I'm not too sure what closing does actually.

On a related note, I don't think we should answer questions "before they get closed." What was the point of closing the question if someone answers it anyway?

Comment: (1) Thanks.  Hmm, that might be the case.  (2) If a question is closed, a user cannot add an answer to it (I do not know about moderators.  You can edit an answer to a closed question).  Also, a closed question can be deleted by voting (by users with lots of rep).  (3) I agree that we should not answer questions hastily just because they are about to be closed, but that deserves another thread.

Comment: Once a question is closed, it can't earn rep for either the poster or answers.

Comment: @Suresh: Oops, I voted your comment, but after some testing, I do not think what you wrote is correct.  It seems that even after a question is closed, it can be voted and votes on the question and answers affect rep.

Comment: @Suresh: I also did some testing, and it seems that questions and answers still seem to add rep, even if the question is closed.

Comment: ah true. however, no new answers can be added.

Comment: FYI: [What is a "closed" question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) on Meta Stack Overflow.